# Sharing Cloud Foundry spaces - why and when

Tags: cloud-foundry, paas

Trying to understand why it's a good idea for a distributed dev team to work in "one" common CF org and space... and what the downside is of not sharing the same space.

After talking to several folks quite knowledgeable of CF, my conclusion is that it's a good idea to share the space for the following two reasons:
1. if there is a high inter-dependency across individually developed / deployed services, .. and / or ...
2. is there is a fee for each service instance, and hence you would want to limit the number of service instances per project

In all other scenarios, it does not really matter.  Developers can collaborate on GitHub, and do pushes within their own individual spaces.

Did I get that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I can explain the base idea of spaces in cloud foundry. ( I don't sure what is your project and if it'll fit you)

If you don't use a cloud, usually you will have 3 servers (minimum):dev,stage, and prod. (again on some type of projects you don't need it)
The dev space is for the developers (let's say you creating a website, one of your developers finished a page in the site he\she uploads it to dev space). 
You and your devs can see the status of the deployment in this space
once you think dev is stable enough (or end of the sprint if you in agile methodology) you move dev space to staging 
in staging usually QA looking for defect and make sure everything works (any bug found in here is opened on the dev team which fixing it on dev and so on)
once staging is tested you move it to prod 
cloud foundry supports this mechanism using spaces

org is for different projects 

all I said here isn't enforced in any way by cloud foundry eventually you can choose the best way that working for you